# Firebase user preferences as android preferences/settings

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm developing an Application using **Firebase analytics, authentication and DB** services.

**I need to save some preferences and some settings, related to the user.**

Most of them are managed in a "SettingsActivity" which is similar to the sample one provided by Android Studio, but with this configuration if the user changes the device, those preferences are lost.

The app should provide a customizable experience for each user. To achieve this I'd like my **preferences to be saved on Firebase insted of in local Preferences.**

*How can I achieve this without have to change too much my app structure?*

**EDIT:**

Here's an example:

The user download my App on first device (Dev-A), he sign up, then he goes to settings and set first setting from A to B, and second setting from A to D.

Then he decide to download my App on a second device (Dev-B), he log in, then he goes to settings.

On Dev-A, first setting is set to B and second setting is set to D.

On Dev-B, first setting is set to A and second setting is set to A.

Comment: You do not need it. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html 
You can backup user data (SharedPreferences) and it will be restored if user change device but use same account

Comment: Not was i was looking for, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to store this information in Firebase Database.

Use the user'd UID you get from Firebase Auth in the Database to store the settings. 
The data should be under '/users/{uid}'

This way, you will persist all user specific data across devices. (Since the same UID will be presented to same authentication account)

Check this link in Firebase documentation to set the [database security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this library:

[A implementation of SharedPreferences which syncs with Firebase database to keep your SharedPreferences in sync between multiple devices of one user and/or to back them up for app re-installs!](https://github.com/crysxd/shared-firebase-preferences)